# search through hard drive for keywords

Tags: c#, java, search

I'm undertaking a project which will be to create a tool that scans through a hard drive searching for specific keywords and outputs the files containing these keywords into a seperate document. I am wondering how long a project like this takes, I have under a year and I am still currently learning to program. Any help would be appreciated as in areas of programming that I should look at before beginning.

It will be for use on Windows and in Java or C#. Will be used for live memory analysis on a system.

Thanks for your time

Comment: How long a project takes depends on the precise requirements and the development team. A year should be plenty. Read into file formats and character encodings.

Answer (score 0):

The GNU `grep(1)` command with , `-R`, `-l` and `-f` command line options could give you this in a few seconds of work. The POSIX-specified `grep(1)` command combined with the `find(1)` command could give you this in a few seconds work. So if you simply want the job done, consider using an existing tool.

Depending upon your skill level, it could take you an afternoon to write a clone of this tool, or it could be a month-long project if it is your first opportunity to learn about Regular Expressions, tree walking, and so forth.

Doing the project in C# would probably give you easier access to files with multiple data forks; this will be vital if your tool will be used in any kind of forensics setting.